# Xcode 4.5 : Merge two static library ,,, Permission denied

Tags: ios, static-libraries, xcode4.5

I am trying to merge to static library into one library.

Here is the script :

```
rm -rf ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/libAggregate.a

lipo -create "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/../${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/libStatic Library.a"
"${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/libStatic Library Device.a" -output "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/libAggregate.a"
```

But I am getting this error

> /Users/Me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Static_Library-bcdrrwpqmxtbqghkamlqbrgjkmfi/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/libStatic
>   Library Device.a: Permission denied

How to fix that?

Comment: Please show us the file perms of that file (using `ls -l`) and updating your question.

Comment: Where I can run that @trojanfoe

Comment: This is what i got when I run ls -1

Adlm
Applications
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Dropbox
FBX Converter 2013.1
Google Drive
Library
Mac OS X Lion 2
Movies
Music
NetBeansProjects
Pictures
Public
Sites
WindowsSupport

Comment: No, run `ls -l` on static library file: `$ ls -l /Users/Me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Static_Library-bcdrrwpqmxtbqghkamlqbrgjkmfi/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/libStatic Library Device.a`.  I want to see it's file permissions.  Then update the question (don't add a comment).

Comment: I got this :  No such file or directory
ls: qbrgjkmfi/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/libStatic-Library-Device.a: No such file or directory

Comment: OK, so there you are.  The file does not exist therefore `lipo` cannot work with it.  Also I think your `lipo` command line is wrong anyway, as I'm pretty sure you need to include the CPU arch as an argument for each input file.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to fix my Lipo command?

Comment: Well first thing is you need to create the static library.  Perhaps Cmd-B might work?

Comment: I have already made them,,, I have two libraries now ,,, the Cmd+b is not working the same error appear each time I build

Comment: I don't know how to make this any easier, but if you already have the static libraries then your script is looking for them in the wrong place ("no such file or directory") so you probably need to fix the script.

Comment: So the 'Permission denied' message related to the file that doesn't exist right?

Comment: I expect so, but I would have thought the message could be better.